# React Typescript component props type inferring

Tags: reactjs, typescript, type-inference, inferred-type

I'm running into a typescript error where I'm rendering a list of components after having mapped some data to them, which is being passed down as props. The requirement is that I slightly mutate this data before rendering.

Below is the typescript part that I want to get right. I have a page which is made up of components in a specific order. I want to infer the type of the component props in this mapping, but having multiple potential component types seems to mess up the infer functionality:

```
// Define the component types
type ArticlePageComponent = typeof ArticleHeader | typeof ArticleSummary | typeof ArticleParticipants | typeof ArticleChapters | typeof ArticleBibliography | typeof ArticleAbout | typeof ArticleFootnotes | typeof ArticleImprint

// Infer component props from component
type ComponentProps<T> = T extends React.ComponentType<infer P> ? P : never

type ArticlePageComponentMap<T extends ArticlePageComponent> = {
  component: T
  props?: ComponentProps<T>
  href?: string
}
type ArticlePageComponents = ArticlePageComponentMap<ArticlePageComponent>[]
```

Below is a screenshot of my `.tsx` file and the error,:

[image]

[image]

I've tried all of the above, ChatGPT, common sense, etc.

Thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: Hi! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Please post code, error messages, console output, markup, data, data structures, and other textual information **as text**, not just as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247